# how to create a search suggestion ComboBox in User form vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

ComboBox drop down list is showing the drop down line items, is there any option to get ComboBox will show dynamic (search suggestion)?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: tried to use this vba coding
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "SearchDrList"
ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub

Comment: while typing in comboBox need to show drop down list pop-up with matching line items names

Comment: All of the built in methods of ComboBox object are taken into account only when something already happens. Unfortunately editing a combo box is not a change for Microsoft :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as I did it in the past. What you need is:

1. capture keypress event in excel application
2. get the currently edited cell's value

   - To do this, you must do a following hack:
     2.1. Save content of the clipboard into a variable
     2.2. Send programmed Ctrl-A and afterwards Ctrl-C keypress
     2.3. Save content of the cliboard as second variable
     2.4. Load content of first variable back to the clipboard
     2.5. Use second variable's content int the next step.
3. dynamically create a collection based on the value
4. put that collection as the new combo box value list
5. show the list to user (unfold combobox)

EDIT: 2nd point requires a "hack". Added.

Comment: To get the currently edited cell's value used this formula =CELL("contents"), but user form edit is not capturing by this formula.

Comment: Do a hack in that case - save into a variable what the user has in his current clipboard, do a coded ctrl-a keypress and then ctrl-c keypress, so you capture current edit value of the user into the clipboard. Extract clipboard to the second variable. Load clipboard from the first variable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Iam in VBA learning stage. it will be great help, if you can get code for the same.  if suppose need to get copied data to sheet1!B2 and combobox name is ComboBox1

Comment: Sorry, currently on mobile with limited access. I suggest googling paraphrases of every step I wrote :) For example: "how to capture keypress in Excel", "how to send a keypress to Excel", "how to work with the clipboard in the vba"...

Comment: Searched in google, couldn't find any suggestion. Can you help out with  this?